# Camera calibration algorithm on Android. (Color Calibration)

Tags: java, android, c++, algorithm, colors

I already researched, and I know there are similar questions to mine, but I have not found a satisfactory answer. **Because I'm talking about color calibration.**

So if anyone can help me, thank you.

Well I've been looking for an algorithm for Camera calibration, but so far I have not found anything.

I need to photograph a certain color in different Androids devices. The purpose is to get the RGB of this color, but before shooting I need to calibrate the camera, so I got the best result possible.

If anyone knows of a calibration algorithm, or something about it, or if you can provide me with a study material, I appreciate it.

Note: It is not a matter of geometric calibration, but of color calibration.

Comment: wouldn't it be an option to use a "white balance card" and adjust the color in post?

Comment: @miga Yes, I really need to use that.
But along with the card, would not an algorithm be needed to calibrate?
Ie I need to get the best result on different devices
And for that I need an algorithm to calibrate, correct?

Comment: @miga, Do you have an example algorithm to calibrate the android camera from the white balance card? You could give me an example. Thanks for u help

Comment: No sorry,never did something like that. A balanced card would be used after you take the image you would do the post on machine with all images together. You can't do it on the device because you have different screens that show different color results so you couldn't adjust it to a reference value. What you could do is: take the image, pick the color of the reference card and change the whole image color so you'll have a 128,128,128 grey and then send the image. Then you have some correction but you still have to adjust all images on one machine to get the same overall settings.